# Adding groups as members to Connections activities with SBT?

Tags: java, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

In IBM Connections, it's possible to add a group (defined in an LDAP directory or similar) as an activity member.
Is it possible to do this with the Social Business Toolkit Java SDK? If so, how?

I can see in the Javadocs that there's an `ActivityService.addMember` method.
This requires a `Member` instance, and constructing a `Member` seems to require a user id.

Searching for group names with the `SearchService` never returns any results, and I can't see any other way to find the user id of a group.

Edit:
Related note from one of my colleagues: Connections also allows adding Communities as Activity members, and we also can't see how to do that in the SBT.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%204.5%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Member_entry_content_ic45&content=pdcontent) the Member category field controls the type of the activity member.

To create a Member group you should leave the contributor email empty, the contributor name should be the group name and the userid should be mapped to the group id

My test env has no groups so I can't confirm with groups directly, but setting as category "community" and userid a community Uuid I managed to add a community as a member to an activity.

**Caveat Emptor:**

When I tried to retrieve the single member from connections using the community member id I got instead the full list of activity members. That also happens when using the REST API by itself with the Location URL returned with the 201 Created result, so it's something happening from the connections side. But as long as creation is concerned, this should be possible.

Comment: Thanks. We'll try with adding a community tomorrow.
How would we get the group id to create group members? Is that assigned by Connections, or by the LDAP directory? As stated in my original question, the SBT `SearchService` doesn't return groups, so doesn't seem to provide a way to find a group id.

Comment: I created a defect corresponding to this on the SBTSDK.  it currently does not exist in the Java API.